# Is there a way to constrain a generic parameter type to the type of a certain property?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, solid-principles

Please consider the following code:

```
public class User 
{
  public String Id {get; set;}
}

public interface IUserService 
{
  bool IsAdmin(string userId);
}
```

I would like to not specify the type of the `userId` parameter in the interface but rather use a generic type that is constrained to be of the same type as the property `Id` in the class `User` so that I don't have to change the code if I eventually decide to change the type of the property.
So what I have in mind is something like:

```
public interface IUserService 
{
  bool IsAdmin<T>(T userId) where T : typeof(User.String)
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: you could also pass the entire `User` into your `IsAdmin` method. Then the person who is forced to implement the interface can then choose which property to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. It's also not very useful to have a generic constrained to one specific type, that defeats the purpose of having a generic.

What you could do is make your own type `UserId` (class or maybe struct) and use that in both places. So if your structure of what a user identifier *is* in your program changes, you can change it in one place and it works all over your program.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a dynamic property?:

`public dynamic Id { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this isn't possible, but as a workaround, you can use a [using alias directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive), provided that both interfaces are in the same file.

In the file that both interfaces are in, add a using alias directive like this:

```
using UserIdType = System.String;
```

Now, you can use `UserIdType` instead of `String` in both `User` and `IUserService`. When you want to change the type of the `Id` property, just change the using alias directive, and you don't have to change the types of either `Id` or the parameter `userId`.

---

However, wouldn't you still have to change the code that depends on the `Id` property? Changing one extra thing isn't that much of a trouble, compared to all the other code changes you'll have to make.